# Gauge invariance for the electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, gauge-invariance

We know that $$\boldsymbol{E}=-\nabla V-\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{A}}{\partial t}$$

$$\boldsymbol{B}=\nabla\times\boldsymbol{A}$$
But I see that the following changes do not change these fields:
$$\boldsymbol{A}\to\boldsymbol{A}+\nabla f$$
$$V\to V-\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$

My question is about $V$, why is the partial derivative with respect to time does not change the electric field? why would $$\nabla\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)=0$$
I don't see that explained anywhere, and I fail to understand how that is so trivial for any function $f$ that depends on position and time.

Comment: Have you tried to just plug the gauge-transformed potentials into the expression of the electric field and see what happens?

Comment: I feel stupid for not thinking about the cancelling terms, thought there is a deeper reason for it. Well, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zero is due to **canceling** the part from **vector potential change** and the **scalar potential change** in the electric field definition.